# Need some help simplifying an expression

Tags: probability, self-study, association-rules

The expression is:

$=\sum_{i=1}^{M}[(\frac{1}{L})^N\frac{1}{M+1}] $

Comment: What happens to $P(X|L)=1/L$ when $L=0$?

Comment: That's why I think I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Yes, you're doing calculations wrong, but this is about the definitions. It can't be calculated this way.

Comment: Isn't U(X|A,B) defined as 1/(B-A+1) so U(X|1,L) = 1/L?

Comment: Ok, but my original question remains unanswered. What happens when $L=0$? $U(X|1,L=0)$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Any hints on how I should proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P(X|L=0)$ is assumed to be $0$, you can remove $i=0$ case from the summation. With some cleaning, we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^{M}\left[\prod_{i=j}^N P(X_j|L=i)\right]P(L=i)=\frac{1}{M+1}\sum_{i=1}^{M}\frac{1}{i^N}$$

This is a [p-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#/p-series) and doesn't have a closed form formula.

Comment: Thank you so much.